# Prove an orthogonal reflection is of the form $T(u) = u - 2 \langle u,v\rangle v$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be an inner product space of dimension $n$. A linear transformation $T : V \to V$ is called an orthogonal reflection if there exists a $(n−1)$-dimensional subspace $W$ such that $T (w) = w$ for $w \in W$, and there exists a vector $v$ orthogonal to $W$ such that $T (v) = −v$. Show that given this $v$, and assuming $v$ is scaled so $||v||= 1$, then $T$ must be given by the formula $T(u) = u - 2 \langle u,v\rangle v$.

Can I have some guidance for this problem? I feel like I'm lacking the tools to solve this, as it's over a general inner product space. I have however verified that $T(v)$ and $T(w)$ give the right outputs

Comment: Hint: If the equation holds for $u=v$ and for $u \in W$ then it holds for all $u$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Once you know what $T(v)$ is and what $T(w)$ is for $w \in W$, you can deduce what $T(u)$ must be for every $u$ in $V$. Indeed, every $u$ can be written in the form $kv + w$ for some $k \in \Bbb C$ and $w \in W$, so it follows that
$$
T(u) = T(kv + w) = kT(v) + T(w).
$$

Comment: I know that $T(v) = -v$ and $T(w) = w$, but how does that relate to what $T(u)$ is?

Comment: @beginner As I wrote in my answer: if $u = kv + w$, then $T(u) = kT(v) + T(w) = -kv + w$.

Comment: Ohhh, how does that relate then to $T(u) = u - 2 \langle u,v\rangle v$?

Comment: Using the formula $T(u) = u-2\langle u,v\rangle v$, you now only need to state/show 3 things. 1: $T$ is a linear transformation, 2: $T(v) = -v$, and 3: $T(w) = w$ for any $w \in W$.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit confused. I've already verified those three things, I'm just having trouble relating it to $T(u) = -kv + w$. Am I trying to figure out what $k$ is?

Comment: Not quite. You have two maps that satisfy these 3 properties. However, you can use these properties to get a formula for $T(u)$. It follows that two maps with these properties must be the same linear map, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: @beginner For what it's worth, $k = \langle u,v \rangle$. As we've established, however, that information is not necessary to reach the conclusion we're after.

Comment: So because these two maps have the same output on $w,v$ they're the same map?

Comment: Yes. Because these two *linear* maps have the same output on $w,v$ *for every $w \in W$*, they're the same map.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, it finally clicked. Thank you!